# I can't change cache-control in nginx / RoR 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have this script:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        expires -1;
        access_log off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0";
        add_header X-Asset "yes";
}
```

But when I look at developer tools in Chrome I see this:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Mon, 12 Feb 2018 16:45:22 GMT
ETag:W/"5a81c436-e5d7f"
Expires:Wed, 14 Mar 2018 16:45:22 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 12 Feb 2018 16:43:34 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

How can I set that CSS and JS must be always realoading on page load. I have site from 3 years now, I really do not change nothing in it.

It's written in Ruby on Rails, and from about week, peoples start to write that they can't open some page because `<% link_to "visits", visits_path %>` redirect them to root_path ...

I can't reproduce this error because on every my browser everything works ok, but once I have this situation and when I open developer tools and reload page to check for some errors, page just load properly. So I thought to always load JS on every page load.

EDIT:

Trying to change like one first answer I still see :

```
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 15 Feb 2018 19:36:38 GMT
ETag:W/"5a85c673-8fb59"
Expires:Fri, 15 Feb 2019 19:36:38 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 15 Feb 2018 17:42:11 GMT
Pragma:public
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Asset:yes
```

Only on Incognito Mode it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I set that CSS and JS must be always realoading on page load

Try this set of headers as [this SO answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/4950680):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

So you nginx config might look like this:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(css | js)$ {
  expires 0;
  access_log off;
  add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  add_header Cache - Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
  add_header X - Asset "yes";
}
```

Comment: Ok it have typo but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Ok ... it's change but only for users which clear browser cache - for example in "incognito mode".